# Single signature P2SH redeem script

Tags: transactions, script, raw-transaction, p2sh

How would one go about creating a single signature P2SH transaction? (Analogous to a "2 of 3 multisig P2SH" but instead I'm asking about a "1 of 1".)  Would one wrap a standard P2PKH scriptPubKey inside of a P2SH redeem script? Or is there a better/preferred way of achieving this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use 1-of-1 msig for a redeem script:

```
OP_1 push(pubkey) OP_1 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

But this one is better:

```
push(pubkey) OP_CHECKSIG
```

And of course, you are welcome to use segwit form

```
OP_0 push(hash160)
```

Comment: Thank you!  With the 3rd (segwit) form, is there an implicit CHECKSIG-type operand?

Comment: no. required for validation data is moved to `witness` part of transaction