# HOW TO SPEND P2SH with Redeem Script Hex?, Already make the transaction but still have some error

Tags: transactions, p2sh, input-script

I HAVE ERROR "**scriptsig-not-pushonly**"
on this

0200000001706d9793f75fb0b47fc0ff8f26a6f5ebeb5f06a5fe50e784983705184b060fba01000000683044022065794dfae7320f7ec02ecc387a00ae761ac34c4373fadb896ff59ce284159f5702206625d2cf48aa3dbbd4020694eada7a09b53f22ac5b96c96a3cf438a59b07b82501032c7c95ea81ebe9b5ccc08b41a3eef4d2fea41c6b868794a91254b8a9c1eadedbffffffff02050d00000000000017a914f0a433b3411b7c1812937977bebd25602f55b68f87050d00000000000017a914ad0d8c12bfae54c92cd998d879030e8b8357a7558700000000

The above script has been decoded

Version: 2
Transaction Size: 219 bytes
Lock time: 0

can someone help me to fix this please..

*sometimes i have problem with maxburntamount, or stack failed bla bla.*

I just have some experiment, to call P2SH transaction with redeem script, my experiment address
https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/addresses/btc/3HU341AbjnD5SzawKtbY66gVczh7QAfFXL

Answer (score 2):

"**scriptsig-not-pushonly**" refers to the consensus rule that the `scriptSig` of a P2SH input must only include push operations (see [BIP16](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki#specification)). Your `scriptSig` not only includes opcodes other than push operations, but actually fails to decode completely.

Here is the result of using Bitcoin Core's `decodescript` with your `scriptSig`:

`44022065794dfae7320f7ec02ecc387a00ae761ac34c4373fadb896ff59ce284159f5702206625d2cf48aa3dbbd40206 OP_SUB OP_UNKNOWN OP_UNKNOWN OP_ROLL b53f22ac5b96c96a3c OP_UNKNOWN [error]`

After you fix that, you might also want to check the input and output amounts, as your transaction creates more value in outputs (6666 sat) than it spends (1777 sat).

Comment: Can you help me to make the raw Hex transcation ? or theres provider to help me create the raw HEX transaction ? because before i use https://bc-2.jp/tools/txeditor2.html to help me making the raw hex transaction.

Comment: I got inspired from this https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/68227/single-signature-p2sh-redeem-script

but i can't learn properly, because i'm just new this thing, not a geniue coding.